# Why does Erlang think string module functions are undefined?

Tags: erlang

While learning the basics of Erlang (particularly through [this MOOC](https://www.futurelearn.com/courses/functional-programming-erlang/)), I am working on the [Exercism](http://exercism.io/) Erlang exercises, and I am currently up to [Bob](http://exercism.io/tracks/erlang/exercises/bob).  After consulting the Erlang docs, I have written what I thought should be a functioning solution to the problem, but I am getting a runtime error, and I can't work out what is actually causing it, nor how to fix the problem.  My code compiles fine, and is:

```
-module(bob).
-export([test_version/0,response_for/1]).

test_version() ->
    1.

response_for(Message) ->
    Trimmed = string:trim(Message),
    AllUpper = string:equal(Trimmed, string:uppercase(Trimmed)),
    Empty = string:is_empty(Trimmed),
    EndsWithQuestion = string:equal("?", lists:last(Trimmed)),
    if
        AllUpper -> "Whoa, chill out!";
        Empty -> "Fine. Be that way!";
        EndsWithQuestion -> "Sure.";
        true -> "Whatever."
    end.
```

You can ignore the test_version function, it is required as part of the unit tests you test your code against to check that you have a correct solution.  The unit tests are available [here](http://exercism.io/exercises/erlang/bob/test-suite).  The error that I get on every single one of the function tests is the same, and reads like:

> bob_tests: responds_to_something_test...*failed* in function
>   string:trim/1   called as trim("Tom-ay-to, tom-aaaah-to.") in call
>   from bob:response_for/1
>   (c:/Users/jcoo092/exercism/erlang/bob/_build/test/lib/bob/src/bob.erl,
>   line 8) in call from bob_tests:'-bob_responds/2-fun-0-'/2
>   (c:/Users/jcoo092/exercism/erlang/bob/_build/test/lib/bob/test/bob_tests.erl,
>   line 71) in call from bob_tests:responds_to_something_test/0
>   **error:undef   output:<<"">>

I have looked up what the undef error means, and apparently it means that the Erlang runtime thinks the string:trim() function is undefined (line 8 is the Trimmed = ... line).  I have tried skipping that one and going on to others, but they give the same error.  Clearly I am doing something wrong here, because these functions are listed in the Erlang website's docs, but I really can't see what the problem is.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Executing your code in `Erlang/OTP 20`, it does give me an error but it's not the one you post.

```
** exception error: no function clause matching unicode_util:cp(46) (unicode_util.erl, line 285)
 in function  string:equal_1/2 (string.erl, line 508)
 in call from bob:response_for/1 (src/bob.erl, line 11)
```

Which is due to `lists:last(Trimmed)` taking the last character of the Trimmed string. This is not of type `unicode:chardata()` as the function `string:equal/2` demands both parameters to be.

Enclosing it on a list would solve the mentioned problem:

```
 EndsWithQuestion = string:equal("?", [lists:last(Trimmed)]),
```

Comment: Ah, that'll be the issue!  I hadn't realised that there was a new major version of Erlang out.  Taking a quick squiz at the release notes, it looks like these string functions might well be new to it version 20.  I'm trying to update my install of Erlang now, which I'm guessing will probably resolve it (and then give me the other issue you point out).  I'll comment back here once the update is done.

Comment: Turns out that was indeed the problem.  Trying it out on Erlang/OTP 20 worked - and then gave me the error that you had found, which was handily fixed by the modification you proposed.  Thanks! :)